# If the ratio of a sequence is unbounded, what does that say about convergence/divergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a question I thought I had the answer to, but I made some false assumptions. Say we have $a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{n}$ and we know that $\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}$ is unbounded, does $a_{n}$ converge or diverge?
We know that $\forall M \in \mathbb{R},\exists N:\frac{c_{N+1}}{c_N}>M$. I imagine the sequence to diverge but how to prove this, I don't know. Since if $a_{n}$ would converge it would mean that  $c_{n} \rightarrow 0$ but that would mean that $c_{n+1}$ would have to become infinitely large in order to have $\frac{c_{N+1}}{c_N}>M$ still valid... I'm missing something, can anybody help?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $c_{2n-1} = \dfrac{1}{2^n}, c_{2n} = \dfrac{1}{n^2}$. $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ is absolutely convergent to $1 + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$. However, $\dfrac{c_{2n}}{c_{2n-1}} = \dfrac{2^n}{n^2}$, which is unbounded.

Comment: I see what you did, but I already proved this (although slightly different). But this isn't stating anything about the ratio being unbounded, and that is what I'm looking for. In other words: if I can prove that if $\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}$ being unbounded means that $c_{n}$ will not converge to 0, then I'll have a solid proof. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: If $\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ is unbounded, then so is $\left|\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|$, yes? So $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|=\infty > 1$

Comment: The limit of an unbounded set doesn't have to go to infinity. Take for example {1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8,1,9.....}, this sequence is unbouded but doesn't go to infinity. I believe that holds for all oscillating sequences as well..

Comment: Oh! Within the exact confines of your question, I think the series might well be allowed to converge. I apologize, I misread.

Comment: I've changed my answer to provide an example of a convergent such series, does this fit in the confines of your question?

Comment: I don't think so because that series is stated in a different way. The question is to prove it for all series and I'm quite sure it will diverge. Do you see any gaps in what I did in my last comment?

Comment: Your proof above seems to rely implicitly on the sequence being monotone. Essentially, the sequence can still jump around rather a lot as long as its still getting smaller overall.

Comment: I see what you mean but if you would take the absolute of my steps, it would also be true for a non-monotone sequence right?

Comment: Let's try to apply the argument to my sequence. Pick $\epsilon > 0$, $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $c_n \leq \epsilon$. If $c_k = \epsilon$ and $k\geq N$, $k=N$ and is even. $\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k} \leq 1$, as expected. But, $\frac{c_{k+2}}{c_{k+1}} > 1$, since the odd-index terms are vastly smaller than the even terms.

Comment: Also, clarified the notation of the answer a bit